# Powershell Script to rename TXT file based on certain criteria

Tags: datetime, powershell, recursion, rename

I realise it is likely the each of the requirements listed below is available individually within the forum here but I am struggling to bring it all together (if at all possible!).

Hoping someone has the patience and time to point me in right direction to make this happen.

---

What I need to do is the following:

1. Scan a directory (and all sub-directories) for a particular filename

   **NOTE:**  Whilst there are many files within the sub-directories with the filename in question, we only wish to target those in a sub-directory with a suffix of **JERRY**

   ie. In the below example the files indicated by the arrow would be targeted

   ```
   ONE\NEW1-JERRY\FILENAME.TXT   <----
   ONE\NEW1-TOM\FILENAME.TXT
   ONE\NEW1-SYLVESTER\FILENAME.TXT
   TWO\NEW2-JERRY\FILENAME.TXT    <----
   TWO\NEW2-TOM\FILENAME.TXT
   TWO\NEW2-SYLVESTER\FILENAME.TXT
   THREE\NEW3-JERRY\FILENAME.TXT    <----
   THREE\NEW3-TOM\FILENAME.TXT
   THREE\NEW3-SYLVESTER\FILENAME.TXT
   FOUR\NEW4-JERRY\FILENAME.TXT    <----
   FOUR\NEW4-TOM\FILENAME.TXT
   FOUR\NEW4-SYLVESTER\FILENAME.TXT
   ```
2. When file is found matching the filename and is within the sub-directory listed above take a copy of the file (to remain in same directory) & rename based on the following criteria:

   a) Created date/time

   b) Certain content within the file

   The content in the file is always located on ROW 8 and it is the first 9 characters

   **Original filename:** FILENAME.txt

   **Finished Product:** FILENAME-*20121129@1300*-123456789.txt

---

#### **Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

you should tell us what have you tried so far and what are your mains problems...
try this :
(remove the -whatif flag to actually copy files)

```
#list dir & subdirs
ls c:\ -recurse |
    Foreach { 
        #find subdirs named JERRY
        if($_.PSIsContainer -and $_.name -match "JERRY"){
            ls $_.fullname -filter 'FILENAME*' |
            Foreach{ 
                $fcontent=get-Content $_.FullName
                $content=$fcontent[7].Substring(0,9)
                $newName=Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d"
                $destination="$($_.Directory)\$newName@$content.txt"
                write-verbose $destination
                Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $destination -WhatIf 
            }  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help this script does what I am after - a quick question regarding the line ---> `$newName=Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d"` - **is this retrieving the system date/time or the create date/time from the original file?**


If the answer is system date/time can you please provide the syntax to return the create date of the original file?

**Thanks!**

Comment: `$newName=($_.CreationTime).toString().split(' ')[0]` 
dont forget to mark post as an answer please

Comment: **Thanks again for your help!** With a slight tweak your command gave me what I was after:     `$newName=($_.CreationTime).toString("yyyyMMdd@hhmm").split(' ')[0]`                                 _Now that I have caught up the backlog of text files I would like to filter only those files created in the last 24 hours to run as a daily task, are you able to assist with modifying the script to take care of this ?_  **Thanks in advance!**

Comment: **Another option if available would be to skip file copy & rename if file with new name already exists in directory? Thanks!**

Comment: first y ou should mark the post as answer or usefull if it bas helped you